# Using parametric mixins on Bootstrap class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

I am learning LESS while building a site with Bootstrap. I have a Bootstrap carousel with captions. Modifying Bootstrap's class `.carousel-caption` I've used absolute positioning to place my captions where I want them for the majority of my slider images and it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50% !important;
    right: 10% !important;
    top: 50px !important;
    z-index: 10;
    color: @dk-gray;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;

    h3 {
    font-family: @gotham;
    .bold;
    font-size: @font-size-base + 1;
    }

    p {
        font-family: @whitney;
        .normalized;
        font-size: @font-size-base - 2;
    }
}
```

However, I have a couple of slider images that I want to position the caption differently.
So I tried to use parametric mixins with default values to accomplish this:

```
.carousel-caption(@left: 50%, @right: 10%, @top: 50%) {
    position: absolute;
    left: @left !important;
    right: @right !important;
    top: @top !important;
    ...
}
```

This did not work. Is it because I can't use an existing Bootstrap class? Do I have to construct a mixin that I insert within the caption class? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why it didn't worked...?

Comment: Is there any error when you compile the file? Please, give us some more information...

Comment: Did you actually used the mixin? Notice that a mixin definition itself does not generate any CSS code, you need to invoke/call/expand/inject the mixing within a CSS selector you need these properties in. E.g. `.carousel-caption-A {.carousel-caption(50%, 10%, 50%)} .carousel-caption-B {.carousel-caption(25%, 33%, 42%)}` etc.

Comment: That was it. I didn't actually call the mixing within a CSS selector. Now it's working perfectly. Thanks very much!

Comment: @seven-phases-max: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mixin definition itself does not generate any CSS code, you need to invoke the mixing within a CSS selector you need these properties in. E.g:

```
.carousel-caption-A {
    .carousel-caption(50%, 10%, 50%);
}

.carousel-caption-B {
    .carousel-caption(25%, 33%, 42%);
}
```

etc.